# RabbitMQ client hanging up in channel.close() and connection.close()

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I am using amqp-client in java but JVM hangs up infinitely while closing channel.
If I remove `channel.close()` it jvm hang up infinitely on `connection.close()`.
I went through API classes and saw that in both cases RabbitMQ API take timeout as infinite an it just waits reply.
Please tell if their is any workaround to this.
I am using amqp-client-3.1.3.
Many thanks.

Comment: Not sure why you tagged this with `spring-amqp`; you don't appear to be using it. You can always use the `close` variant that takes a timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figure out the solution to the problem
Memory of the rabbitmq server was full.
It started working as soon as i cleared it.

Comment: I have 6 GB free and still face this issue. A Google search for "rabbitmq channel close hang" gives me this thread. Were you able to successfully resolve this issue?